# Selecting rows based on criteria of other rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Hopefully you can help.  I'm storing data in a MySQL database in the following format:

```
ArticlePK   ArticleId   Status      Title               lastupdate
1           1           Draft       Peter Pan           2013-06-14 07:24:05
2           1           Published   Peter Pan           2013-06-15 08:00:05
3           1           Deleted     Peter Pan           2013-06-20 11:30:12
4           2           Published   Growth of the Soul  2013-06-14 07:24:05
```

I need a SQL query that:

- Returns all rows with a Status of Publish
- EXCEPT if a later row (determined by lastUpdate column), with the same ArticleId, has a Status of Deleted.

Therefore, in the following example, the query should only return the row with ArticlePK of 4. The row of ArticlePK 2 will not return due to the row with ArticlePK 3.

I've tried a few things but nothing has worked out.  I'm sure it will only take a nudge to help me out, so if you have any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
SELECT articlepk, articleid, status, title, lastupdate 
FROM   tablename t1 
WHERE  status = 'Published' 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   tablename t2 
                       WHERE  t1.articleid = t2.articleid 
                         AND  t2.status = 'Deleted' 
                         AND  t2.lastupdate > t1.lastupdate)
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39a33/4/0)

Comment: Definite +1 for the SQLFiddle - I didn't even know that site existed.  I'm going to try these answers in more detail tomorrow morning in MySQL, as it seemed to have some issues with NOT EXISTS when I tried it earlier today.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table1 b ON (b.ArticleId = a.ArticleId and b.Status ='Deleted' and 
 b.lastupdate > a.lastupdate)
WHERE a.Status='Published' and b.ArticlePK IS NULL
```